# Typescript callback union parameter overload error "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature."

Tags: typescript

When I try to overload this function with different callback params i run into an error `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.ts(2394) database.ts(41, 3): The implementation signature is declared here.`

```
listen(onData: (data: number) => void): void
listen(onData: (data: number[]) => void): void
listen(onData: (data: number | number[]) => void): void {
  ...
}
```

According to this q [Typescript: specifying multiple callback types in a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757061/typescript-specifying-multiple-callback-types-in-a-union) it appears that you can do it, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Edit:
The actual implementation of the function:

```
  listen(
    ref:
      | firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
      | firebase.firestore.CollectionReference,
    onData: (data: ReadData<T> | ReadData<T>[]) => void
  ): () => void {
    return ref instanceof firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
      ? ref.onSnapshot((doc) => onData(this.txDocData(doc)))
      : ref.onSnapshot((snap) => onData(snap.docs.map(this.txDocData)))
  }
```

Comment: You might not understand [function parameter contravariance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).  You can call `listen()` either with a callback that expects a `number`, or a callback that expects a `number[]`.  That means the implementation sees `((data: number) => void) | ((data: number[]) => void)`, which is really very different from `(data: number | number[]) => void`.

Comment: Can you explain what the actual use case is?  What will the implementation of `listen()` pass to `onData`?  It really can't do anything the way you've declared the call signatures; see [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3YAw).

Comment: I've updated with the actual implementation. txDocData returns ReadData<T>, and the .onSnapshot returns different objects based on if the reference is a single document or a collection of documents. If it's a dingle doc, it returns a single item and vice versa

Comment: Okay, I see.  I can write up an answer but the issue is one of contravariance; you'll probably be happier with just `onData: (data: any) => void` inside the implementation signature, or refactoring to give up on overloads and use a discriminated union rest tuple instead.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use an onData function where the param is typed - so if a discrimnated union rest tuple solves that, then great :) If not - i'd probably just separate it into two functions for the different refs.

Comment: Can't write an answer just now but [this](https://tsplay.dev/KwXpkw) is my thought process.  The rest tuple thing will work but I'm not sure if it's worth it.  Overload implementations are generally pretty loose so I'd say the `(data: any) => void` might be fine for your use case

Comment: I tried applying it to my function but didn't have success unfortunately. I'll probably separate it into two functions but I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks are different types. They are not compatible. They just happen to be functions.

```
function listen(onData: (data: number) => void): void
function listen(onData: (data: number[]) => void): void
function listen(onData: ((data: number) => void) | ((data: number[]) => void)): void {
    onData([42]);   //Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & number[]'.
                    //    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
    
    onData(42);     //Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & number[]'.
                    //    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.(2345)
}
```

Try to think the other way around: If I call `listen()` with a cb that expects to be called with a `number[]` it must not be called with a `number` by the implementation. I declared that cb can only be called with a `number[]`. The same goes the other way.

The only solution for the compiler is to enforce that onData is called with a parameter that is a `number` *and* a `number[]` at the same time - hence the type `number & number[]`